# Parse the content we get from copy and paste using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a project and I am stuck on a very weird issue. I have to restrict what content we receive from copy and paste on an input box. For instance, if only numbers are allowed in the input boxes. I would like user to not be able to paste anything other than numbers. Or if they paste anything and leave the input box then remove anything that is not a number. Is it possible using jquery?

```
<input onKeyPress="return filterNumber(event)" type="text" id="phone">

function filterNumber(evt){
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The above function 'filterNumber' won't allow user to enter anything other than number while they type. But it won't prevent them from pasting anything like alphabets, symbols and numbers.

I tried google but I didn't find any solution for this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to do that.

> Or if they paste anything and leave the input box then remove anything
>   that is not a number

In this example, when user enters some text to the input (including copy-paste), we get and *remove/replace* all of the characters which are not numeric.

```js
function filterNumber(input){
  input.value = input.value.replace(/\D*/g, '');
}
```

```html
<input oninput="return filterNumber(this)" type="text" id="phone">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it does for work for me. I have tried pasting using the mouse, keyboard. It's working for now. I haven't tried it with different browsers right now but I think I will use your solution. Thanks @Tan

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't listen for key events for pasting. What if I paste with the mouse? There's a dedicated [`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) event.

The second advantage of this approach is that the event data contains [clipboard data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData), which you can retrieve and interrogate before you even allow it into your text field.

```
let ta = document.querySelector('textarea');
ta.addEventListener('paste', evt => {
    let pasted = evt.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    if (/\D/.test(pasted)) { //<-- contains any non-numeric chars?
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert('Only numbers allowed, matey!');
    }
});
```

If the pasted input contains non-numeric characters, we cancel the operation by suppressing the event's default action (which is, of course, to paste the text.)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kfduxjg8/)